# Android Fragment, No view found for id inside TabHost

Tags: android, android-widget, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I have a simple Android application with tabs set up using Tabhost and Fragments. On one of the tab pages, the fragment is a listview. What I want to do is when a user clicks on one of the items of the list view, open up a new view with more specific information based on the item clicked but preserving it so that the tabs are still there.

My approach is when a user clicks on a item in the listview, a new fragment is created and then from my main FragmentActivity class that owns all of these fragments and handles the tabbing logic, it will detach the currently shown fragment and add this "new" (singleStationListItem) fragment. The issue I am encountering is that I cannot add my new fragment to the fragmentTransaction with the R.id.realtabcontent and thus, it is not properly added. I get:

03-21 10:50:01.862: E/FragmentManager(1136): No view found for id 0x1010000 (android:attr/theme) for fragment singleStationListItem{40d090a0 #2 id=0x1010000}

where R.id.realtabcontent = 0x01010000;

I can attach it without the Id, but then users are not able to go back ( call addtobackstash() ). I have searched for this errors but other solutions do not relate to tabhost and I seem to do what is required, like call setContextView(...) in onCreate() to the xml file of the layout that includes the framelayout tag that I am trying to attach my fragment to. I can add my tab fragments to the R.id.realtabcontent without a problem. Does anyone know what could be causing my error and how I can fix it?

Note: I follow this tutorial for getting my tabs working. My code is very similar.
http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/

My Code:
activiy_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_body"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:padding="5dp" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+android:id/realtabcontent"  <--id that I want to set to
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

main_activity.java //parts from my fragment activity class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Step 1: Inflate layout
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Step 2: Setup TabHost
        initialiseTabHost(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab")); //set the tab as per the saved state
        }
    }

public void onTabChanged(String tag) { //handles tab changes
    TabInfo newTab = (TabInfo) this.mapTabInfo.get(tag);
    if (mLastTab != newTab) {
        FragmentTransaction ft =     this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (mLastTab != null) {
            if (mLastTab.fragment != null) {
                ft.detach(mLastTab.fragment);
            }
        }
        if (newTab != null) {
            if (newTab.fragment == null) {
                newTab.fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this,
                        newTab.clss.getName(), newTab.args);
                ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent, newTab.fragment, newTab.tag); //note it uses the R.id.realtabcontent without any issues here
            } else {
                ft.attach(newTab.fragment);
            }
        }

        Log.d("fragment manager in activity: ", "" + ft.isEmpty());
        mLastTab = newTab;
        ft.commit();
        this.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        Log.d("ft ID: ", ft.toString());
    }
}

//This is the callback function inside the listview fragment. I created an interface and it is overwritten in here as suggested by the Android SDK guide
public void onStationSelected(String station) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);

    //create argument for new fragment that will be created
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("station", station);
    Fragment displayStationInfo = Fragment.instantiate(this, singleStationListItem.class.getName(), b);

    Fragment cur = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.realtabcontent);
    ft.detach(cur);
    ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent, displayStationInfo); <-- this line causes the error
    ft.commit();
    this.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
}
```

singleStationListItem.java is here

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle b = this.getArguments();

    getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.single_station_item_view);

    TextView txtStation = (TextView)   getActivity().findViewById(R.id.station_label);

    String station = b.getString("station");
    // displaying selected product name
    Log.d(TAG, "passed in station information: " + station);
    txtStation.setText(station);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_station_item_view, container, false);
    return v;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question was asked a while ago, I am posting an answer for others that may come across this question.

As far as I know, there is no Android id of 'realtabcontent'. In your XML, remove the 'android' part of your id for the `FrameLayout`.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

The complete XML code posted on the [developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html) is as follows:

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Good luck and happy coding!